# What is the problem in the codes?

Tags: pstricks, preview, pst-tree

See the code given below.
Actually, I am looking for a tree of number 36.

Can somebody let me know what I did wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{levelsep=1,treesep=1,nodesep=2pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\preview
\psTree{\TR{36}}
\Tcircle{2}
\psTree{\TR{18}}
\Tcircle{2}
\psTree{\TR{9}}
\Tcircle{3}
\Tcircle{3}
\endpsTree
\endpsTree
\endpsTree
\endpreview
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't really understand, the only thing preventing that code from running is `\preview` and `\endpreview`. They presumably come from the `preview` package, which you don't load, but I don't think you would need it here anyway. If you remove those two lines, does it work for you? If not, can you tell us which error message you get, or otherwise what the problem is?

Comment: Just a minute i am sending the errors.

Comment: line 24: Undefined control sequence. \preview

Comment: As I said, does it work if you remove `\preview` and `\endpreview`?

Comment: Still ,not works when i follow your instruction.

Comment: And which error do you get now?

Comment: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}

Comment: Undefined control sequence. \psTree

Comment: line:28 Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{18}}

Comment: No way you get those errors with the code in your question, you must have somehow removed `\usepackage{pst-tree}` and the `\psset` line.

Comment: Sorry, i have to send all the errors in the form of a new questions.

Comment: No, just edit this one.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Hi snehal and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Hi snehal. I think we're going to 'close' this question for the moment, but this does not mean you won't get an answer. Once you've cleaned up the original question with all (or most) of the needed information, I'll nominate the question for re-opening myself. In its current form, a good answer to your question simply isn't possible (largely because the question itself is unclear).

Answer (score 2):

My crystal ball reports that the first error you got is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
```

then multiple errors of the form

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@ 
                                                  \fi \space 
l.25 \Tcircle{2}
```

Tcircle here is just the location of the error (line 25) the undefined command is `\@@` but always with TeX it is best to ignore all but the first error.

You are using pstricks which requires latex and dvips, not pdflatex. If you use pdflatex you get the errors shown,

The posted code, if used with latex, runs without error, then you need to use dvips and ps2pdf to get PDF output.

Comment: If this is right then the question is a dupe ...

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the environment `preview`. Use package `auto-pst-pdf` and the environment `postscript` instead if you run it with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{tikz}
\else
  \usepackage{pst-tree}
  \psset{levelsep=1,treesep=1,nodesep=2pt}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
    \psTree{\TR{36}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\TR{18}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\TR{9}}
    \Tcircle{3}
    \Tcircle{3}
    \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

Using `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` makes life easier. Then you do not need package `auto-pst-pdf` and the environment `postscript`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}% xelatex <file>
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{levelsep=1,treesep=1,nodesep=2pt}

\begin{document}
    \psTree{\TR{36}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\TR{18}}
    \Tcircle{2}
    \psTree{\TR{9}}
    \Tcircle{3}
    \Tcircle{3}
    \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
    \endpsTree

\end{document}
```