# errors while compiling the following codes

Tags: errors

In the connection of my previous question.

[What is the problem in the codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288996/what-is-the-problem-in-the-codes)

Codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{levelsep=1,treesep=1,nodesep=2pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}    
\psTree{\TR{36}}
\Tcircle{2}
\psTree{\TR{18}}
\Tcircle{2}
\psTree{\TR{9}}
\Tcircle{3}
\Tcircle{3}
\endpsTree
\endpsTree
\endpsTree
\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
line 49: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 49: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 49: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 49: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 50: Undefined control sequence.
line 50: Undefined control sequence.
line 50: Undefined control sequence.
line 50: Undefined control sequence.
line 51: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{18}}
line 51: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{18}}
line 51: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{18}}
line 51: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{18}}
line 53: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 53: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 53: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 53: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{2}
line 54: Undefined control sequence.
line 54: Undefined control sequence.
line 54: Undefined control sequence.
line 54: Undefined control sequence.
line 55: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{9}}
line 55: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{9}}
line 55: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{9}}
line 55: Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\TR{9}}
line 57: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 57: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 57: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 57: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 58: Undefined control sequence.
line 58: Undefined control sequence.
line 58: Undefined control sequence.
line 58: Undefined control sequence.
line 59: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 59: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 59: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 59: Undefined control sequence. \Tcircle{3}
line 60: Undefined control sequence.
line 60: Undefined control sequence.
line 60: Undefined control sequence.
line 60: Undefined control sequence.
: You have requested release `2014/05/01' of LaTeX, but only release `2011/06/27' is available.
```

Comment: It would appear to be the case that the macros `\Tcircle` and `\psTree` aren't defined. This could happen because, e.g., a package that defines these two macros has inadvertently not been loaded.

Comment: 1) Please don't ask identical questions. 2) You can edit your questions. 3) Your code does *not* produce any errors at all.

Comment: So sorry for that,

Comment: But i seem errors. Is there any other issue?

Comment: Instead of that list of errors, can you add the contents of the `.log` file?

Comment: also please edit the question title to be something useful for search the current title could apply equally to every question here

Comment: I'm voting to close this one, please add the actual log file (as far as the first error) to your duplicate question.

Comment: Extremely sorry for all that.

Comment: First: there is no line number 49 in your code. Thus, the error message is from different document than your code. Second: the format of "undefined control sequence" message differs. This message alone is in one line. Then, in the next lines, we can see, where is problem. The message is never followed by `\Tcircle` in the same line. The result: you are not using TeX.